# Android Paho SSL with server sent CA certificate, including Hostname Verification

Tags: android, ssl, mqtt, paho

**Duplication**: There are a few similar questions ([How Can I Access an SSL Connection Through Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441158/how-can-i-access-an-ssl-connection-through-android), ["Trust anchor for certification path not found" in Android SSL Socket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665062/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-in-android-ssl-socket-client), [Trust anchor for certification path not found using SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494992/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-using-ssl))
with no applicable answers to my issue. I try to give a specific context (e.g. paho and specific test sites) and problem.

**Main Issue**: I'm using Android Paho, as client, and everything's fine. Now I want to add SSL connection. The broker is the certified entity, and sends its CA-issued certificate during handshake.
(Please note that I'm a security newbie, I just read a few tutorials on the subject.)

Most Java and Paho examples I can find deal with having a *local* certificate (self-issued, or less known CA, etc.), while I need instead to manage CA-issued certificates sent to my app by the broker server during handshake.

From Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), the idea seems to be that you just have to use `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`, since root CA certifications for well-known CAs are included with the system. So, simply:

```
MqttConnectOptions options;

// ...

options.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
```

But I tested on both:

- ssl://iot.eclipse.org:8883
- ssl://test.mosquitto.org:8883

and I always got the dreaded `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

The possible reasons given by the aforementioned android documentation, and Stack Overflow answers, presumably don't apply to such well-known and used test sites. I presume that both sites have updated certificates, issued by well-known Certification Authorities, with no lesser known CAs in the chain. (While I cannot find clear confirmation, usage examples around the net do seem to imply it.)

Any pointers? I really have no idea where to go from here (and I presume I'm missing something obvious that it's not clearly stated.)

**Secondary Issue**: Furthermore, the Android documentation warns that `SSLSocket` doesn't do any Hostname Verification: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#WarningsSslSocket

And hence it suggests:

```
SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("gmail.com", 443);
HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
SSLSession s = socket.getSession();

// Verify that the certicate hostname is for mail.google.com
// This is due to lack of SNI support in the current SSLSocket.
if (!hv.verify("mail.google.com", s)) {
    throw new SSLHandshakeException("Expected mail.google.com, "
                                    "found " + s.getPeerPrincipal());
}
```

Please note that you need a reference to the actual socket to pass to `verify()` (no overloaded alternative), you cannot just configure the `SSLSocketFactory`.

Paho doesn't seem to expose access to the socket it's using, not to set a custom verifier. You can only set the `SSLSocketFactory`.

If I understand correctly, there seem to be a Paho bug reported about it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425195

Is it actually the same issue?

Finally, if so, is there any way to work around this and actually have Android Paho over SSL with Hostname Verification?

**EDIT, Partial answer / findings**: I record here my partial provisional findings.

My assumption about `iot.eclipse.org:8883` and `test.mosquitto.org:8883` seems to be wrong: I found doc for both that provide certificates to explicitly be used by the clients (I presume self-signed, it's not specified). Some examples omitting this misled me.

- ssl://iot.eclipse.org:8883 :  [iot.eclipse.org.crt](http://iot.eclipse.org/iot.eclipse.org.crt) as indicated by http://iot.eclipse.org/getting-started
- ssl://test.mosquitto.org:8883 : [mosquitto.org.crt](http://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/mosquitto.org.crt) as indicated by http://test.mosquitto.org/

Loading the certificates in a custom `TrustManager`, everything work. Mystery solved on this point. Our own broker with CA certificates isn't ready yet to be tested.

Comment: iot.eclipse.org:8883 uses a self-signed certificate. test.mosquitto.org:8883 uses a certifucate issued by a custom mosquitto.org CA and is therefore equal to a self-signed certificate.

Comment: How do you deal with certificate renovation? I mean, "loading the certificates in a custom TrustManager" implies you have to put the .crt file in the package.